# facing issue to call service ionic app CORB

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, cross-origin-read-blocking

Getting following issue for only one service in my ionc4 app

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response MY URL with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

I added CORS extension to my chrome browser and added that service url still i am getting same issue.

Comment: Please post your code and what you've tried so far, it would also be helpful if you post the exception you're getting

Comment: i am not getting any exception it returns null value

Comment: it showing Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response MY URL with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details. in chrom console

Comment: i am just calling http post method passing req obj ,in headers tokens and content-type is application/json

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```